# Bitcoin Core full node has saved a lot more space than 260gb

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, storage, blockchain-data-storage

I've had Bitcoin Core running on my Macbook i5, 8gb ram, the last five nights and have gotten to 58%. It's downloading to an external hdd and now the blocks directory contains 375gb of data.

Another computer, Huawei laptop i5 8gb ram, started downloading it yesterday and has gotten to 61% with just under 200gb or storage space used. Although this computer first downloaded to its internal ssd and then I copied it to the hdd. Now its crashing all the time in the same way the first has been for the last days.

I cant figure out why its saving more than the original blockchain. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/17827) and a bug with APFS. This will be fixed in the next version of Bitcoin Core.